# Kinect ~ Virtual Booth

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, tracking, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way I can crop the tracking area? Like where it only tracks someone skeleton in the specific area, so if someone is in the certain depth and certain X/Y value it will track them. If they walk out it drops that person from being tracked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9479/kinect-%7E-virtual-booth/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a NITE question.  I suggest that you ask on the [openni-dev mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Alright thanks for the direction.